# Given two points, constructing a hyperbolic line

Tags: circles, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm asked to write an equation of the hyperbolic line that passes through $2+3i$ and with endpoint at infinity $3$. Clearly, this line is a semicircle on the real axis. However, I need some hint to proceed.

Comment: Is this question about the [Poincaré half-plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model)?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is about Poincâre half-plane model.

Comment: you have two points on a circle. The perpendicular bisector of the segment between them passes through the center